# How do I remove the newlines from this string?

Tags: c#, newline

I've spent many, many hours looking for answer.  If you look up remove new lines on this site, it gives answers that looks like would work, but I can't get those to work.

```
string TextFileBlock = File.ReadAllText("TextFile.txt");

 char newlinechar = '\n' ;

 TextFileBlock = TextFileBlock.Replace(" ", String.Empty); //works for the spaces

 TextFileBlock = TextFileBlock.Replace(newlinechar.ToString(), String.Empty);

///Does not get rid of the newlines. The enter key.

      // TextFileBlock = TextFileBlock.Replace("\n", String.Empty);// not works
      //TextFileBlock.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);//not works
```

C# question

Comment: You know on Windows, a new line consists of a carriage return followed by a line feed `\r\n`, not just `\n`? If you're ever in doubt of what the characters are in your file, look at it in a hex editor such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

Comment: By that logic the OP code should have removed the \n and left the \r.

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of it:

```
public static string RemoveNewLines(this string input)
{
    return input.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\r", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: It's better to just `return input.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty);` since those 2 methods take care of `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is reasonably small, you can replace the entire segment with:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile.txt");
string TextFileBlock = String.Concat(lines).Replace(" ", "");
```

The [`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns an array of lines, where a line is terminated by a carriage return (`\r`), line feed (`\n`), or CRLF (`\r\n`).  Individual elements in the array do not include the terminating carriage return or line feed, and are thus not included in the final string when the array elements are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 and later make newline replacement or removal extremely easy.

`TextFileBlock = TextFileBlock.ReplaceLineEndings("");`

`ReplaceLineEndings' can also be used to replace, e.g. Windows newlines with Linux/Unix/Mac newlines:

`myString.ReplaceLineEndings("\n");`

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replacelineendings?view=net-7.0